# Session data not being saved on some mobile versions of Safari

Tags: authentication, mobile-safari, session-variables

It works just fine on my iPhone 3GS, but several employees with iPhone 4 and up are not able to log into my site through safari because their login credentials are not being saved to $_SESSION. If they download chrome onto their phones it works.

Any idea how to get this working?

When a user attempts to log in, their credentials are first verified as being accurate, and when they are they are sent to:

validate_login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// sent from the login form
// employee id and username
$employeeId = $_POST['employee_id'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//make connection to database, bail if no connection
$connection = odbc_pconnect('workorders','','');
if (!$connection) { exit("Connection Failed: " . $connection); }

//retrieve usernames and passwords
$sql = "SELECT * FROM LoginTable WHERE EmployeeID='$employeeId' and Password='$password'";
$rs = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
if (!$rs) { exit("Error in SQL"); }

if(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    // register employeeId and password in session cookie and redirect to homepage
    $_SESSION['employee_id'] = $employeeId;
    header("location:../../home.php");
}
else {
    header("location:../../login.php?error=0");
}

//close connection
odbc_close($connection);
```

?>

This is about as simple as you can be... any idea why it wouldn't be working? When I do a check at the top of every page that they are logged in:

```
<?php
session_start();

//validate user logged in; if not, redirect to login
if(!isset($_SESSION['employee_id'])){
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

?>

It just thinks they're not logged in and throws them back out to login.php

Again, this is just an issue on Safari for newer iPhones as far as I can tell. Suggestions?